# How many morphemes in words most/worst

Tags: linguistics, morphology

My intuition tells me that they are both 2 morphemes, where /t/ represents the superlative form.

Comment: There are two morphemes, but this is a suppleted form instead of an affix. Like _good, better, best_, the comparative and superlative of _bad_ are also formed by suppletion: _bad, worse, worst_. So the morphemes in _worst_ are {_bad_} + {_-est_}; similarly _most_ is {_much_} + {_-est_}, but this is just root variation, not real suppletion.

Comment: Similar: [Is “best” monomorphemic?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451048)

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> There are two morphemes, but this is a suppleted form instead of an affix. Like *good, better, best*, the comparative and superlative of *bad* are also formed by suppletion: *bad, worse, worst*. So the morphemes in *worst* are {*bad*} + {*-est*}; similarly *most* is {*much*} + {*-est*}, but this is just root variation, not real suppletion.